# ¿Como sumar elementos de un array de objetos con js usando reduce?

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo el siguiente array de objetos quiero sumar las edades de todas las personas:

```
let personas = [
    {id: 1, name:'Darinel', edad: 24, lastName:'Cigarroa', ciudad: 'CDMX'},
    {id: 2, name:'Darwin', edad: 24, lastName:'De jesus', ciudad: 'CDMX'},
    {id: 3, name:'Vera', edad: 24, lastName:'Dominguez', ciudad: 'CDMX'},
    {id: 4, name:'Emiliano', edad: 24, lastName:'Silva', ciudad: 'CDMX'},
    {id: 5, name:'Derky', edad: 24, lastName:'Wilner', ciudad: 'CDMX'},
    {id: 6, name:'Juan', edad: 24, lastName:'De La Cruz', ciudad: 'CDMX'},
];
```

Estoy intentado  de esta manera pero sin resultado alguno:

```
let reduce = personas.reduce((acumulador, actual) => acumulador.edad + actual.edad);
console.log(reduce)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Estas casi correcto. El acumulador en este caso sera un numero entero no un objeto (no tiene propiedad edad) y debes darle un valor de inicio (en este caso 0)

```js
let personas = [
    {id: 1, name:'Darinel', edad: 24, lastName:'Cigarroa', ciudad: 'CDMX'},
    {id: 2, name:'Darwin', edad: 24, lastName:'De jesus', ciudad: 'CDMX'},
    {id: 3, name:'Vera', edad: 24, lastName:'Dominguez', ciudad: 'CDMX'},
    {id: 4, name:'Emiliano', edad: 24, lastName:'Silva', ciudad: 'CDMX'},
    {id: 5, name:'Derky', edad: 24, lastName:'Wilner', ciudad: 'CDMX'},
    {id: 6, name:'Juan', edad: 24, lastName:'De La Cruz', ciudad: 'CDMX'},
];


let reduce = personas.reduce((acumulador, actual) => acumulador + actual.edad, 0);
console.log(reduce)
```

Answer (score 1):

Recorriendo el objeto con el método ***forEach()*** y acumulando en variables.

```
 let personas = [
  {id: 1, name:'Darinel', edad: 24, lastName:'Cigarroa', ciudad: 'CDMX'},
  {id: 2, name:'Darwin', edad: 24, lastName:'De jesus', ciudad: 'CDMX'},
  {id: 3, name:'Vera', edad: 24, lastName:'Dominguez', ciudad: 'CDMX'},
  {id: 4, name:'Emiliano', edad: 24, lastName:'Silva', ciudad: 'CDMX'},
  {id: 5, name:'Derky', edad: 24, lastName:'Wilner', ciudad: 'CDMX'},
  {id: 6, name:'Juan', edad: 24, lastName:'De La Cruz', ciudad: 'CDMX'}
];

var sumaedad    = 0;
var nropersonas = 0;

personas.forEach( function(persona){
         sumaedad    += persona.edad;
         nropersonas += 1;
 })
console.log( ` Cant.Persona: ${nropersonas} la suma de edades acumula: ${sumaedad} `);
```